# Outlook comobject overwrites files without prompt

Tags: powershell, outlook, overwrite, office-automation, save-as

I'm writing a little script that would batch convert `.msg` files to `.pdf` with `.html` in the middle, all while saving attachments. While this is a work in progress I encountered a strange thing.
If a file with the same `.fullname` as the attachment is already present in the folder it gets overwritten, no prompt.
Is there a way to force confirmation on `.SaveAsFile` method for the attachments? See current script below.

```
$o = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$1 = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
Set-Alias -Name chrome -Value $1

Get-ChildItem -file -filter *.msg | ForEach-Object {

    $msgFullname = $_.FullName
    $htmlname = $msgFullname -replace '.msg', '.html'
    $attloc = $_.Directory

    $msg = $o.CreateItemFromTemplate($msgFullname)
    if ($msg.Attachments.Count -ge 1) {
        $msg.Attachments | ForEach-Object {
            $attname = $attloc.FullName + "\" + $_.FileName
            $_.SaveAsFile($attname)
        }
    }
    $msg.SaveAs($htmlname, 5)

    $dest = $_.DirectoryName + "\" + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"
    $source = $_.DirectoryName + "\" + $_.BaseName + ".html"

    chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=$dest  $source --print-to-pdf-no-header

    $1 = $_.BaseName

    Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.BaseName -like "*$1*") -OR $_.Name -like ($_.BaseName + "*.html") } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
}
```

Comment: Assuming you mean the ```SaveAsFile``` method for Attachments (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile), there doesn't look to be any parameters to control prompts for overwriting, *but* you could pretty easily add a check yourself with ```Test-Path``` before calling ```SaveAsFile```...

Comment: @mclayton Thanks. I've edited the question to be more consistent. I've thought about using Test-Path. Will let you know later if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer I am presenting a modification of the script from the first post.
In this, the script checks if a file with the same name as attachment is already present and if it is, another name is given. particularily a '-' and a number are added at the end.

```
$o = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$1 = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
Set-Alias -Name chrome -Value $1


function att_inc
    {
        $attname = $attloc.FullName + "\" + $_.FileName.substring(0,$_.Filename.Lastindexof('.')) + '-' + $counter + $_.FileName.substring($_.Filename.Lastindexof('.'))
        main
    }


gci -file -filter *.msg|%{

 $msgFullname = $_.FullName
 $htmlname = $msgFullname -replace '.msg', '.html'
 $attloc = $_.Directory

 $msg = $o.CreateItemFromTemplate($msgFullname)
    if($msg.Attachments.Count -ge 1){
    $msg.Attachments|%{
    $counter = 0  
    $attname = $attloc.FullName + "\" + $_.FileName      
            function main {
                if((test-path $attname) -eq $false){
                $_.SaveAsFile($attname)
                } 
                    else {
                        $counter++
                        att_inc
                         }
                         }
            main
}
}
msg.SaveAs($htmlname, 5)

$dest = $_.DirectoryName + "\" + $_.BaseName + ".pdf"
$source = $_.DirectoryName + "\" + $_.BaseName + ".html"

chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=$dest  $source --print-to-pdf-no-header

$1 = $_.BaseName

gci|?{($_.PSIsContainer -eq $true -and $_.BaseName -like "*$1*") -OR $_.Name -like ($_.BaseName + "*.html")}|remove-item -recurse -force




}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no prompt, and there shouldn't be one - if you are programmatically saving a message/attachment, it is your responsibility to check if the file already exists and what to do with it.